# Convertir Uri a Bitmap y guardar la imagen en el dispositivo

Tags: android

Trato de convertir Uri a Bitmap con este método:

```
try {
          Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PostDetailActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", new File(Uri.parse(mPost.getPhoto()).getPath()));
          Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
          saveImageToExternalStorage(bitmap);
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this, "Error during download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Pero, recibo el siguiente error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains
>   /v0/b/example-app-android.appspot.com/o/photos/ZdOLPeM2k4fSimyfzyySRSkfiaU2_20180911_011804.jpg
>           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:738)
>           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)

Para guardar la imagen en el dispositivo tengo esto:

```
private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images_1");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
        // immediately available to the user.
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Provider:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

provider_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Alguna idea del problema?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa el AndroidManifest.xml que se genera al compilar. Debe estar en una ruta similar a app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug dentro de la carpeta de tu app

Comment: @JaviMollá No logro encontrarlo. Exactamente cómo puedo llegar a el? y de qué me serviría revisar el AndroidManifest generado?

Comment: Revisa el valor de android:authorities. Fíjate en la ruta que te puse ya que debería estar en una similar dentro del directorio de tu aplicación

Comment: @JaviMollá Lo he logrado y en `authorities` dice `com.example.app.fileprovider`.

Comment: Era por confirmar que com.example.app coincide con el package base de tu aplicación

Comment: Acabo de ver que estás usando getExternalStoragePublicDirectory ¿No se supone que con ese método estás guardando en la parte pública del dispositivo? Por lo que yo entiendo, no tiene nada que ver con el FileProvider

Comment: @JaviMollá La verdad no se cuál usar pero, el código no llega a esa parte todavía, el se queda en el `try-catch`.

Comment: el package del manifest coincide con getApplicationContext().getPackageName()?

Comment: @JaviMollá Si, son iguales.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83086/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-robert-gomez).

Answer (score 0):

En Kotlin, lo hago con esa función

```kotlin
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun saveImageToPNG(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap, name: String = "share.png", folder: String? = null) {
    val fos: OutputStream
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val resolver = context.contentResolver
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/$folder")
        val imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
        fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri!!)!!
    } else {
        val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
        ).toString() + File.separator + folder

        val file = File(imagesDir);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }

        val image = File(imagesDir, "$name.png")
        fos = FileOutputStream(image)

    }

    val saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
    fos.flush()
    fos.close()
}
```

Su uso, es simple

```kotlin
saveImageToPNG(requireContext(),  bitmap)
```

la guarda en la galeria con el nombre por defecto share.png, se puede especificar un nombre y carpeta.

En mi dispositivo tras ejecutar esa función se actualiza la galeria y me aparece las imágenes.